# Why can't I connect to my Kodi server from my Ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, network, smb

i’m trying to connect to Kodi (running on LibreElec) from my iOS (iPad) device.
In Kodi, I have settings>services>samba enabled. No login & password.

In iOS, I went to Files app > menu > connect to server.

I did try with *smb://192.168.1.7*; or *smb://LIBREELEC*; both as a guest or with credentials, but it does not work. Sometimes it shows a popup notice (*an unexpected error occured*), other times it seems to work; but there is no files list + it says it is read only.

Note that I CAN connect to Libreelec from my (linux) laptop.

Any ideas of what it might be ? Thanks !

Comment: I had problems with accessing a username/password-less Samba server via Files in the past. Do you have an option to define a user on your Kodi device and try again?

Comment: Can you see the logs on the kodi or make a Smb share from your Linux computer? It should be easy to determine where the fault lies with either of these to test / observe.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that UPnP is turned on in settings in Kodi, then download Ark Mc lite from the iTunes store and look if it can see your Rpi. Mine does, but I am using an old version of the app on a 1st gen iPad. Or jailbreak the iPad and install Kodi, which will then see anything else running Kodi on your network.

Comment: This is not a Raspberry Pi but an Intel NUC.  Enabling UPnP didn’t work.  I just want to connect to the Kodi HD.  Shouldn’t be so complicated!  It works with my computers.  Is this related to iOS ?